# what if the index doesnt exist

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this if statement

```
<?php if(in_array($product['product_id'], $selected_products['business'])) { ?>
```

but sometimes the array `$selected_products` doesnt have the index `business` .. how can i alter the if condition without have an outer if statement

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do if the index doesn't exist.

If you only want to perform this check if the index is there, add an `isset()` check before it (line break for clarity):

```
if (isset($selected_products['business'])
    && in_array($product['product_id'], $selected_products['business'])) {
```

Additionally, if you need to do something else in the event the index isn't there, attach an `else` block.

Comment: I think `)` is missing after `isset($selected_products['business']`

Answer (score 3):

Short circuit `isset` using the && operator. With short circuit evaluation, the second expression isn't evaluated if the first one fails.

`<?php if(isset( $selected_products['business']) && in_array($product['product_id'], $selected_products['business'])) { ?>`

Comment: .. and this is useful to prevent an error message from appearing. (+1 otherwise)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [logical AND operator `&&`](http://php.net/language.operators.logical) to combine both expressions:

```
if (array_key_exists('business', $selected_products) && in_array($product['product_id'], $selected_products['business']))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ternary statement, that line will be a bit busy though:

```
<?php if(in_array($product['product_id'], isset($selected_products['business']) ? $selected_products['business'] : false))) { ?>
```